# I want to give jQuery Slider many value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know that the jQuery Slider has a value option.
It is defined as a number or an array.

But I want to give more value to the value.
I want to make it like a picture.

[image]

I know the library named 'noUiSlider', but I want to be able to create multiple reference points directly on one slider bar.

What Should I do?

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
  values: [ 10, 25 ]
});
```

Comment: please check your question... add some code, and explain better what you need

Comment: DaFois In fact, I am a Korean and do not speak English very well. I'm sorry.

Comment: http://quarterto-archive.github.io/Elessar/ could be helpful.